# Android App to open html fetched from SQL server

Tags: android, sql

I would like to store HTML files on a SQL server, these html files will be forms that need filling out.

I would then like my Android app to connect to the sql server and open a specific html file.

I have code for submitting my html form data to the sql server. Just not sure how to fetch the html file from the server and view it in my app.

n.b. refering to ( http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/12153-Sending-form-data-from-HTML-page-to-SQLserver-2005-database-by-calling-servlet-code.html ) for sending html data to sql server

Any help/ideas

thanks, 
Rob

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to use a `WebView` and set its location to the URL used to retrieve the HTML file from the server.